# Find Data From JSON Base on Value and Show in Html

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

How to find data, Base on a key value. I want only id 03 data on my HTML

file name: data.json

```
[ { 
          "id":"01 ",
          "prouctName":"Chair ",
          "Price": "251"
       },
     
       {
        "id":"02",
        "prouctName":"Table",
        "Price": "685"
       },
       {
         "id":"03",
         "prouctName":"Table3",
         "Price": "68565"
       } ]
```

I am using jquery for running this

file name: index.html

```
 <table id="table">
     </table>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON("./multi-seater/list.json",
            function(data) {
                var pName = '';
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                    pName += '<tr>';

                    pName += '<td>' + value.prouctName + '</td>';
                    pName += '<td>' + value.Price + '</td>';

                    pName += '</tr>';
                });

                $('#table').append(pName);
            });
    });
</script>
```

itis like

my key value id:**01** and  prouctName:**Table3** or Price**68565**

and fetch only data for id 03 in my HTML in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the find expression as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON("./multi-seater/list.json",
            function(data) {
            var findResult = data.find(x => x.id == 03); //use == for lookup
                if(findResult)
                {
                    var pName = '';
                    pName += '<tr>';

                    pName += '<td>' + findResult.prouctName + '</td>';
                    pName += '<td>' + findResult.Price + '</td>';
                    pName += '</tr>';

                    $('#table').append(pName);
                }
        
            });
    });
```

Comment: you can play with = == operator.

Comment: If possible can explain me with complete code inside of index.html

Comment: is not work it is always returns the first value  prouctName and Price